# How to store dropdown selection into variable and print it on console?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to bind my dropdown selection into a variable and print it in console. How can i do this?

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control box" id="title" required>
    <option *ngIf="nationality_flag">{{nationality}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let lists of default_nationality">{{lists}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="selectedChanged()" class="form-control box" id="title" required>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  selected:string;
  selectedChanged() {
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
}
```